# How do I solve the string formula for this dependent data validation in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm having the issue for the string formula to key in my dependent data validation:

[image: Error for the data formula]

The plan is to:

```
****ROOMS****                                            **PRICE** 
3+1 Bedroom Premier Suite, 1 King - 1 Queen -       (FROZEN) > no price data at here            
3 Single bed (Inclusive breakfast for 6 pax)
```

When we choose the type of room, at the price column it will refer on which bar prices we can choose from it such as `750.00`, `690.00`, `630.00` or `600.00`.

[image: The full data is as below]

Comment: You should really at least include the formulas with which you are dealing and possibly a table of your data.

Comment: I want to match up the type of rooms and price together. say that if we choose 3+1 Bedroom Premier Suite, 1 King -  1 Queen - Single bed (Inclusive breakfast for 6 pax) from the data validation at A17, the column at the C17, we are able to choose the bar rate for it, such as 1510, 1380, 1250, or 1190.

I have tried to sort out the Substitute string but get stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you are using the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) the way it was intended. I would recommend opting for a formula based on the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) instead.

Assuming that A17 is an exact match for one of the values in A2:A11, select C17 and choose Data ► Data Tools ► Data Validation. Opt for *Allow: List* and supply the following for *Source:*,

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$11, MATCH($A17, $A$2:$A$11, 0), 0)
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and you should have a dynamic price list in C17 dependent on the room selection in A17.

Comment: Earlier in the point I thought it will be good if I'm using the indirect and the VLOOKUP function to customize this sets of data. 

The sets of Index and Match works perfectly fine! Cool dude! Appreciate a lot for your help to solve this nuts that cracking my head!

Comment: Jeeped, how do i repeat the strings of the dynamic price list? if we choose the same content of the room selection for the next row? Currently when I have re choose the same room selection at A18 , the dynamic price list starts to frozen back at C18.

Comment: If the data validation is to be copied to other cells, then the `$A$17` needs to become `$A17` so that the row will reflect the new row it is copied to.